# Writing to excel file based on column value & string naming

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string

The DF looks something like this and extends for thousands of rows (i.e every combination of 'Type' & 'Name' possible)

```
| total |  big  |  med  | small|   Type   |   Name   |
|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:----:|:--------:|:--------:| 
|   5   |   4   |   0   |   1  |   Pig    |   John   |
|   6   |   0   |   3   |   3  |  Horse   |   Mike   | 
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   Cow    |   Rick   |
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   Horse  |   Rick   |
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   Cow    |   John   |
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   Pig    |   Mike   |
```

I would like to write code that writes files to excel based on the 'Type' column value. In the example above there are 3 different "Types" so I'd like one file for Pig, one for Horse, one for Cow respectively.

I have been able to do this using two columns but for some reason have not been able to do it do it with just one. See code below.

```
for idx, df in data.groupby(['Type', 'Name']):
     table_1 = function_1(df)
     table_2 = function_2(df)

    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{'STRING1'+ '_' + ('_'.join(idx)) + '_' + 'STRING2'}.xlsx") as writer:
        table_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Table 1', index=False)
        table_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Table 2', index=False)
```

Current result is:

```
            STRING1_Pig_John_STRING2.xlsx (all the rows that have Pig and John)
```

What I would like is:

```
           STRING1_Pig_STRING2.xlsx (all the rows that have Pig)
```

Comment: What's about using only type like this: for idx, df in data.groupby(['Type']):

Comment: and then how do i modify the - with pd.ExcelWriter... line to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything against boolean indexing ? If not :

```
vals = df['Type'].unique().tolist()
with pd.ExcelWriter("blah.xlsx") as writer:
  for val in vals:
    ix = df[df['Type']==val].index
    df.loc[ix].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(val), index=False)
```

**EDIT :**
If you want to stick to groupby, that would be :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("blah.xlsx") as writer:
  for idx, df in data.groupby(['Type']):
    val = list(set(df.Type))[0]
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(val), index=False)
```

Comment: would prefer to use a similar method to what I already have just to keep it consistent. Do you know how I might adapt it?

Comment: Just edited it. Not sure which way is the easier to read, though...